# Count values in whole dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe like this. How can i count values in whole dataframe with pandas

Dataframe input

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | D | E |
| B | D | A | G |
| C | A | D | F |
| G | H | E | D |

Output:

| Char | Count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 4 |
| E | 2 |
| F | 1 |
| G | 2 |
| H | 1 |

Comment: Flattening the frame and then counting is a way. @Blaco You may use `pd.read_clipboard`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `melt` to flatten your dataframe then `value_counts` to count the number of occurrence of each letter:

```
out = df.melt(value_name='Char').value_counts('Char').rename('Count') \
        .sort_index().reset_index()
print(out)

# Output
  Char  Count
0    A      3
1    B      2
2    C      1
3    D      4
4    E      2
5    F      1
6    G      2
7    H      1
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to cast the flattened underlying numpy array to Series:

```
pd.Series(df.values.ravel(), name='count').value_counts()
```

ouput:

```
D    4
A    3
B    2
E    2
G    2
C    1
F    1
H    1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

If you really need a DataFrame with the above format:

```
(pd.Series(df.values.ravel())
   .value_counts()
   .sort_index()
   .rename_axis('char')
   .reset_index(name='count')
)
```

output:

```
  char  count
0    A      3
1    B      2
2    C      1
3    D      4
4    E      2
5    F      1
6    G      2
7    H      1
```